# How use content type ModelAndView in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

When Using this code

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public ModelAndView showMessage(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    System.out.println("From controller..");
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    mv.addObject("hello", "Hello");
    mv.addObject("name", name);
    return mv;
}
```

View page

```
 <body> 
  <p>${hello} ${name}</p>
</body>
```

The "From controller" message in the server result but when print variable "hello" and "name" then it does not show in the view JSP page

Comment: how do you add variables in jsp page?

Comment: Add your JSP code.

Comment: ${hello} ${name}

Comment: you haven't set the view. `mv.setViewName`

Comment: How to set mv.setViewName

Comment: mv.setViewName("nameOfJsp")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
mv.setViewName("index");
```

you can also use:

```
public String showMessage(Model model)
model.addAttribute("hello", "Hello");
return "index";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your jsp `<%@ page isELIgnored = "false" %>` Right now your jsp might be ignoring the EL language that is `${''}` 
Furthermore You are setting the view name in

```
ModelandView modelandview= new ModelandView("index");
```

so there is no need for this

```
modelandview.setviewName("index");
```